# Efficiently accessing array within array

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

I have a data type called `Filter` which has an `NSMutableArray` property which holds a bunch of `FilterKey` objects (different amount of keys for each filter). I have a bunch of these `Filter` objects stored in an `NSMutableArray` called `Filters`.

I have a `UITableView` for which each row is populated with data from one of the `FilterKey` objects. My question is, for a given row in the UITableView, how can I use the `Filters` array to find the right `FilterKey` (considering I've already put the Filters and Keys in order manually)?

Basically, I know I could just traverse through the `Filters` array and for each `Filter` object, traverse through all it's `FilterKeys`, but I'm wondering is there a better way to do this (ie better data structure, or something that would give me the right object faster?

Sorry if this is confusing if you have any questions please let me know in the comments.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, I just want to say that your username is perfect! Well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would use sections and rows for this, where each section is a Filter and each row is a FilterKey.

It sounds like you just want to show the filter keys, and not have section headers for their filters (if I'm reading your post correctly). If you don't actually want headers, that's fine, just return 0 for `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `nil` for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

All of this is really more for convenience than performance. It is unlikely that it will be much faster than running through the filters and adding up the counts of their keys. That kind of operation is extremely fast. But sections/rows maps your data better, so I'd probably use it anyway to keep the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is hash-mapped resulting in faster, easier, readable operations.

If you prefer arrays then there is no need to traverse to search for a specific value, you can use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to filter your array.